# some help understanding ajax code please

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

i went trough some tutorials but the code i inherited is probably advanced.
can some one help me understand this code and explain it to me step by step please? all i know is, when i update/change the mood desc and color, the actual wording of the mood desc and color i typed in changes color...

```
function ax_update_mood()
{
   //what is it doing here?
   var  str_mood_desc    = $('#moodmeter_form_mood_desc').val();
   var  str_mood_color    = $('#moodmeter_form_mood_color').val();

  //understand this part
  if(str_mood_desc.length  < 3  || str_mood_desc.length > 32)
  {
 alert('Mood Description must be between 3 - 32 characters long.');
 return
  }

 //understand this part
 if(str_mood_color.length  < 1  || str_mood_color.length > 32)
 {
alert('Mood Color must be between 3 - 32 characters long.');
return
 }

//have NO idea on what is going on here!
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "moodupdate",
data: "mood_desc="+str_mood_desc+"&mood_color="+str_mood_color,
success: function(msg)
{
  ax_get_mood();
  alert( "Mood Updated");  
}
})
}

function ax_get_mood()
{
    //this is also a complete mistery, have no idea what this code does
$.getJSON('/apps.php/profile/getmood', function(data) 
{
    //const TIME_DIFF = 180; 
    var td_mood_color       = $('#current_mood_color');
    var td_mood_desc        = $('#current_mood_desc');
    var spn_mood_updated_at = $('#spn_updated_at');

    if(data.date_diff_in_min < 180)
    {
        spn_mood_updated_at.removeClass().addClass('span_mood_red');
    td_mood_desc.removeClass().addClass('span_mood_red');
   td_mood_color.removeClass().addClass('span_mood_red');
    }
    else
    {       spn_mood_updated_at.removeClass().addClass('span_mood_blue');
        td_mood_desc.removeClass().addClass('span_mood_blue');
        td_mood_color.removeClass().addClass('span_mood_blue');
    }

    spn_mood_updated_at.text(data.mood_updated_at);

    td_mood_color.text(data.mood_color);
    td_mood_desc.text(data.mood_desc);

});
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article for the basics of AJAX, which you have probably already done.

In summary, three steps:

```
//Step 1. get the XMLHTTPRequest object
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) //All mordern browsers
{
    obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) //IE6, 7
{
    obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} 
else
{
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX");
    return;
}

// Step 2: set the callback function, as processMoodUpdateResponse
//This function will be called when the response for the 
//call (done in step 3) comes back

obj.onreadystatechange = processMoodUpdateResponse;
// Step 3: Do the server call. 
//"POST" is the request type, true for asynchronous request
var url = "moodupdate?mood_desc="+str_mood_desc+"&mood_color="+str_mood_color
obj.open("POST", "moodupdate", true);
obj.send();

//The callback function
function processMoodUpdateResponse()
{
      ax_get_mood();
      alert( "Mood Updated"); 
}
```

The code you have inherited uses [JQuery Ajax.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

The following creates an Ajax request, registers the callback and submits, is equivalent to the above (and of course more *jquerish* and simpler)

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "moodupdate",
data: "mood_desc="+str_mood_desc+"&mood_color="+str_mood_color,
success: function(msg)
{
  ax_get_mood();
  alert( "Mood Updated");  
}
})
```

The [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is another method from jQuery, to make a server call and get a [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/) response. It is strange that a Ajax callback (that is called when a response comes) makes another ajax call.

`$('#current_mood_color')` is equivalent to `document.getElementById('current_mood_color');`. This is jquery's way of selecting an element by its id. JQuery as a very powerful (and convenient) [selector API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), and this is one of the basic ways of selecting an element.

`#someThing` refers to an element with id `someThing`, so searching for `someThing` in your codebase will return something.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the offical docs and everything should become clearer :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems to understand the syntax, the code is using JQuery library to get value from moodmeter_form_mood_desc and moodmeter_form_mood_color, to send ajax request to target, and to parse JSON data.

For more info, see: http://jquery.com/, search jQuery.ajax() and jQuery.getJSON()

Comment: thanks all i will follow the links provided.
just one thing: what does this line mean??: 
    $('#current_mood_color');

i grep'd #current_mood_color and did not find this code anywhere??

Comment: It must be somwhere in the page html. It can be anything with id current_mood_color (normally it should be an <input>). Have you tried to find it in html code?

Comment: `grep current_mood_color` (without the `#`) should return something. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is using jQuery. The first 2 lines of the function simply get the value of 2 elements (probably `input` elements), and assign those values to variables.

The `$.ajax` part is using the jQuery `ajax` function to send data via an HTTP POST request, to whatever file resides at the URL `moodupdate`. The data sent is built up as a string on the following line, using the values obtained earlier.

The next line specifies a function that will execute upon success of the AJAX request. That function in turn calls the `ax_get_mood` function, which uses the jQuery `getJSON` function to make another asynchronous request to `/apps.php/profile/getmood`, and process the response (which will be in JSON format, as hinted at by the use of `getJSON` rather than another `ajax` function) in another anonymous function.